# Jackson ObjectMapper ignore a given class

Tags: jackson

I have this bean

```
class Toto
{
    private final String fuu;
    private final String bar;
    Private List<Dog> dogs;
}

class Dog {
 private String name;
 private String race;
}
```

I want to convert this bean into a Map<> using:

```
ObjectMapper serializer = new ObjectMapper();
serializer.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
return serializer.convertValue(entry, Map.class);
```

This code result is that Dog objects are also converted into a Map.

I want a solution so that in the final map i would have:

```
fuu=fuu_value_as_String
bar=bar_value_as_String
dogs=[ObjectDog1, ObjectDog2] // i do not want the Object to be  
converted (because i have an instanceof check later in the code)
```

Thanks